# Describing the everting motion of cylinders and Mobius bands.

Tags: differential-geometry

I was attempting to describe the inside out motion that is realised by turning a  Moebius band which has no self intersections.The Moebius band considered would be a ruled surface parametrised as

$$\boldsymbol\sigma(t,\theta)=\left(\left(1-t\sin\dfrac\theta2\right)\cos\theta,\left(1-t\sin\dfrac\theta2\right)\sin\theta,t\cos\dfrac\theta2\right),$$ where the domain of definition of $\boldsymbol\sigma$ is $$U=\{(t,\theta), \mid-1/2<t<1/2,\ 0<\theta<2\pi\}.$$

However I am unsure whether the right way is to model this phenomenon as a family of isometries or through time evolution of the ruling vector taken as a hinge and rotating about the midline? I found a paper on inverting a cylinder by Halpern and Weaver.

Comment: Google search with keywords crossing belts mobius strip animation

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank you for the comment. But what exactly am I looking for?I didnt get any obvious results with the google search.

Comment: https://visualizingmath.tumblr.com/post/63335749093/a-cool-rotating-m%C3%B6bius-strip-animation-a-m%C3%B6bius

Comment: @JeanMarie Thnaks. Unfortunately as the post clarifies, that is not a Moebius strip. But regardless, the math behgind it is still not clear to me.